# pySpark - join on nullable column, conditional join

Tags: python, sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a pyspark code that joins two DFs on 3 columns:

```
final_df = spark_company_df
 .join(
    spark_geo_df,
    (spark_company_df.column1 == spark_geo_df.column1) &
    (spark_company_df.column2 == spark_geo_df.column2) &
    (spark_company_df.column3 == spark_geo_df.column3),
    "left_outer")
  .select(
    spark_geo_df.column1,
    spark_geo_df.column2,
    spark_geo_df.column3)
```

**spark_company_df.column3** can be null and the other two can't so in those cases all 3 columns are null in resulting DF. Is there any easy way to join on 2 columns if 3rd is null and join 3 columns if it's not null, some kind of conditional join. I know I could do it with additional join but maybe there is a better way to do it?

Desired final DF:

```
-----------------+--------------------+-------------+-
|column1          |        column2     |      column3|
+-----------------+--------------------+-------------+
|               LA|                  CA|           US|
|               LA|                  CA|           US|
|               SF|                  CA|         null|
+-----------------+--------------------+-------------+
```

but getting:

```
-----------------+--------------------+-------------+-
|column1          |        column2     |      column3|
+-----------------+--------------------+-------------+
|               LA|                  CA|           US|
|               LA|                  CA|           US|
|             null|                null|         null|
+-----------------+--------------------+-------------+
```

Comment: Could you add sample of your input dataframes?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pyspark.sql.Column.eqNullSafe](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.Column.eqNullSafe.html) to achieve that,

Your code will be something like this,

```
final_df = spark_company_df
 .join(
    spark_geo_df,
    (spark_company_df.column1 == spark_geo_df.column1) &
    (spark_company_df.column2 == spark_geo_df.column2) &
    (spark_company_df["column3"].eqNullSafe(spark_geo_df["column3"])),
    "left_outer")
  .select(
    spark_geo_df.column1,
    spark_geo_df.column2,
    spark_geo_df.column3)
```